# rxjs TypeScript filter support

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to filter an observable array of numbers with rxjs. However, as type hint, TypeScript tells me that the filter operator gets a `number[]` array, instead of a `number`, which I don't think is correct. According to [the docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/filter.html), the rxjs filter operator predicate should accept one item, not an array of them. Is this an error in the TypeScript typings, or is there an error in my example below?

[image: filter support]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter()` operator is correct here. Problem is because you are passing array to the `of()` which will create `Observable<number[]>`, **alternatively you need to use `from()`, which will create `Observable<number>`.**

---

### *Edited after question from author

**Thus updated example will be:**

`from([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]).pipe(filter(x => x > 3)).subscribe(x => console.log(x));`

This will print:

4

5

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So I'm guessing a map operator in combination with a pure JS-filter inside is more what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to filter arrays I would propouse:

```
of([1,2,3,4,5]).pipe(map(array => array.filter(element => element < 3)))
```